Connecting problem to another user's PostgreSQL database in Django
I have a question. I'm starting to work on a Django project. I received database credentials for a PostgreSQL database created by a colleague. How can I connect to this database?
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "guizo"

Unfortunately, after starting the Django server, the error shown in the attached screenshot appears in the terminal.
Please help. Thank you!

Please post the error as a text, not a screenshot.

I see some problems here.
First, you are connecting to localhost. Is this what you want?
If you try to connect to a colleagues database, it might not run on your machine and you want to enter a proper host there?
I can see the password authentication failed for user "guizo" (you might want to anonymize this kind of data) Have you checked the version of the PostgreSQL you are connecting to has the user and you have configured the password correctly? Have you tried logging into this user via the command line Interface of PostgreSQL?
You can configure your connection to the database from your Django Settings module/file.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/
Without more information or the settings file I don't see any further information

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
